# Code Contracts warning about possibly failing 'Assume' call

Tags: c#, code-contracts

In a class of mine, I have a private field of type `ExpandoObject`. The field is initialized in the constructior (`this.expected = new ExpandoObject()`), so I'm confident that it will never be `null`.

Thus, in one of the methods on this class, I fell safe to add

```
Contract.Assumes(this.expected != null)
```

before using `this.expected` for anything, so Code Contracts won't have to worry about possible calls on null objects. However, instead of a warning for possible method call on a null reference, I get a warning saying

> The dynamically dispatched call to method 'Assume' may fail at runtime because one or more applicable overloads are conditional method

The method signature and the first few lines of code looks like this:

```
protected void Expect(object values)
{
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(values != null);

    Contract.Assume(this.expected != null);
    var exp = (ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)this.expected;
```

On the third line, I get a warning for

> CodeContracts: Possibly calling a method on a null reference 'OddEnds.Testing.TestBase.o_*SiteContainer0.<>p*_Site3.Target'

where I assume the odd signature of the null reference is because `exp` is a dynamic object.

How do I solve these?

Comment: You talk of thefield, extended, expected.  Seems like they are all the same field but impossible to reverse-engineer.  Review your question for accuracy.

Comment: Sorry - I was a little too fast there... As you assumed, they are all referring to the same field, which is now called `expected`, as it is in my code.

Comment: wonder whether same warning will exist if you replace Assume with Assert?

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to solve your problem is to declare that `expected` is never null as an invariant on the class:

```
class TheClass {

    ExpandoObject expected;

    ...

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    void Invariants()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(this.expected != null);
    }

    ...

}
```

When you do this, the static checker will check that `expected` is not null at the end of your constructor, and then it will know that `expected` is never null at the start of any other method.

Comment: That is quite sexy! =) I will probably go with this both here and in some other cases as well, but I have a follow-up question: are invariant contracts disposable-aware? I.e., can I implement `IDisposable` without breaking a `blaha != null` contract in the `Dispose` method?

Comment: As long as you don't set `blaha` to `null` it will be fine. :) (Actually, you could implement a perverse type that had `==` depend on whether it was disposed or not, and that could break it... but that's just nasty anyway.)

Comment: But if I have `blaha = null;` in the `Dispose` method it will break?

Comment: Yup. The invariant is checked at the end of every method. You could try using `Contract.Invariant(disposed || blaha != null)` with a flag variable `disposed`, but I think you'd have to then add a precondition `Contract.Requires(!disposed)` to your methods. Is there any particular reason you need to set `blaha` to `null`?

Comment: No, I was just wondering =) Unfortunately, this was not the root cause - now, CC is complaining that the invariant cannot be verified...

Comment: I tested it with the code you originally posted and it was OK... it should be telling you a line where it is failing, usually the end of a method.

Answer (score 0):

Im thinking following code change will keep compiler happy (if your sure in this cast anyway, but why use expandoobject then.. anyway)

```
ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>> col = this.expected as ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>;
Contract.Assume(col != null);
```

Comment: I had that before, but changed it to an explicit cast to keep the compiler happy :P